# How to add hair particles to a material in an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, hair

I have an object with two materials, and I want the hair particles to only grow on the second material.  How do I do this?

Comment: Use a vertex group. Create a vertex group where the material is and use it for the density parameter  of the particles.

Comment: Just to be clear you can't directly assign particles to materials, not even to faces. You can only use vertex groups to control density